# Using an enum for an instruction set for two bytecode interpreters with different word lengths in C#

Tags: c#, generics, enums, bytecode

I am creating a class library in C# for a bytecode interpreter as a coding exercise. I have two bytecode interpreters, one using 32-bit words, the other using 64-bit words.  I want to create a unified instruction set that is shared between both interpreters.

I thought of using generics to solve this problem like I would with templates in C++:

(C++ Code)

```
template<typename T> 
enum Instruction : T {
    add,
    subtract,
    ...
}
```

And I would have have the 32-bit interpreter use `Instruction<int32>` and the 64-bit interpreter use `Instruction<int64>`.

However, after doing a little bit of research I did not find a way to use generics with an enum in C#.

This C# code will not compile:

```
enum Instruction<T> : T {
    Add,
    Subtract,
    ....
}
```

Is there something I am missing here or am I taking the wrong approach entirely?

Comment: Why not share 32-bit instruction set between both interpreters? Or if you want to have 2 class libraries - use [conditional compilation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if).

Comment: If you want your instruction set to be unified, why is there a need for 64-bit instructions? You won't be able to use the additional bits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing generics like that won't work, an alternative I'd suggest is to just default to using `long` for the type, then wrap it in a class which validates the opcode depending on whether it is 32 bit or not.

```
public enum Opcode : long 
{
    Add = 0L,
    Subtract = 1L,
    ...
}

public class Instruction 
{
    public Opcode Opcode { get; }
    public Instruction(Opcode opcode)
    {
        if (is32Bit && ((long)opcode) > int.MaxValue)
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        Opcode = opcode;
    }
}
```

Another option is to use conditional compilation as Dmitry suggested

```
#if IS_64_BIT
public enum Opcode : long
#else
public enum Opcode : int
#endif
{
    Add = 0,
    Subtract = 1,
    #if IS_64_BIT
    Multiply = long.MaxValue
    #endif
}
```